# Responses to NF_STOLEN packets aren't hitting NAT rules

Tags: dhcp, nftables, netfilter

I'm currently working on placing DHCP servers within a Docker bridged network. To ensure packets get through I have the following:

```
table netdev filterearly_lan10{
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device enp1s0.10 priority -500; policy accept;
    
            meta nftrace set 1
            ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff udp sport 68 fwd to "br-a039f83f0bc5";            
    }
```

Using `nft monitor trace` I can see the first packet:

```
trace id e0907bbc netdev filterearly_lan10 ingress packet: iif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 08:00:27:65:d0:37 ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff vlan pcp 0 vlan dei 0 vlan id 10 ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 ip dscp 0x04 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 128 ip id 0 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x1010600e7f4d81b000d0000
trace id e0907bbc netdev filterearly_lan10 ingress rule meta nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id e0907bbc netdev filterearly_lan10 ingress rule ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff udp sport 68 fwd to "br-a039f83f0bc5" (verdict stolen)
```

Followed by the response:

```
trace id a119cb52 inet filter forward packet: iif "br-a039f83f0bc5" oif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 ether daddr 02:42:29:21:39:06 ip saddr 172.25.10.5 ip daddr 192.168.1.134 ip dscp cs6 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 38372 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x2010600e7f4d81b000d0000
trace id a119cb52 inet filter forward rule meta nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id a119cb52 inet filter forward verdict continue
trace id a119cb52 inet filter forward policy accept
trace id a119cb52 inet customblock block packet: iif "br-a039f83f0bc5" oif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 ether daddr 02:42:29:21:39:06 ip saddr 172.25.10.5 ip daddr 192.168.1.134 ip dscp cs6 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 38372 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x2010600e7f4d81b000d0000
trace id a119cb52 inet customblock block verdict continue
trace id a119cb52 inet customblock block policy accept
```

However that's as far as the response packet gets; it doesn't hit any of the NAT chains required to masquerade the response packet IPs. I can see it in `tcpdump -i br-a039f83f0bc5 port 67 and port 68 or arp -nne` but not in `tcpdump -i enp1s0.10 -nn port 67 or port 68`.

For informtion my `postrouting` is:

```
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        
        meta nftrace set 1
        iifname "br-a039f83f0bc5" oifname "enp1s0.10" masquerade;
        oifname "ppp0" masquerade;

    }
```

The `netfilter` [documentation](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.txt) states:

> 3. NF_STOLEN: I've taken over the packet; don't continue traversal.

I wonder if this is having an effect on the response packet too?

How might the response packet be made to traverse netfilter as usual? Thanks

Comment: I think it might be ARP trouble - it's trying to route back the IP given by the DHCP but of course it will get no reply because the client hasn't accepted the IP yet...